# nodejs application starting systemd service using forever

Tags: systemd, nodejs

We have a NodeJs application called **app.j** running on a Linux RHEL machine.   We start the service using the node **forever** module on the command line in the directory the application resides.

```
> cd /usr/app/dir
> forever start app.js
```

This works fine, but now we would like to have **app.js** startup after system reboot so we've created a **systemd** service file that won't seem to work.
I was hoping someone could point out some blatant problems that I don't see.

**/etc/systemd/system/fulltext.service** file

```
[Unit]
Description=FullText Server NodeJS Script app.js
After=network.target

[Service]
Environment="NODE_ENV=lint"
Environment="PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/slsuser/.local/bin:/home/slsuser/bin"
WorkingDirectory=/usr/share/eBSE/current/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/forever start  /usr/app/dir/app.js
ExecStop=/usr/bin/forever  stop   /usr/app/dir/app.js
User=root
Group=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Getting the following error when executing **system fulltext start**

```
fulltext.service - FullText Server NodeJS Script app.js
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/fulltext.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Oct 30 17:07:21 edc-v-slsftx01i04 forever[23421]:     uid  command       script                         forever pid   id logfile                 uptime
Oct 30 17:07:21 edc-v-slsftx01i04 forever[23421]: [0] gMOv /usr/bin/node /usr/app/dir/app.js 23415   23427    /root/.forever/gMOv.log 0:0:0:0.59
Oct 30 17:08:00 edc-v-slsftx01i04 systemd[1]: Started FullText Server NodeJS Script app.js.
Oct 30 17:08:00 edc-v-slsftx01i04 systemd[1]: Starting FullText Server NodeJS Script app.js...
Oct 30 17:08:01 edc-v-slsftx01i04 forever[23514]: warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
Oct 30 17:08:01 edc-v-slsftx01i04 forever[23514]: warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
Oct 30 17:08:01 edc-v-slsftx01i04 forever[23514]: info:    Forever processing file: /usr/app/dir/app.js
Oct 30 17:08:01 edc-v-slsftx01i04 forever[23530]: info:    Forever stopped process:
Oct 30 17:08:01 edc-v-slsftx01i04 forever[23530]:     uid  command       script                         forever pid   id logfile                 uptime
Oct 30 17:08:01 edc-v-slsftx01i04 forever[23530]: [0] dX9T /usr/bin/node /usr/app/dir/app.js 23524   23536    /root/.forever/dX9T.log 0:0:0:0.53
```

Answer (score 0):

*I realize this is an old question and the OP probably doesn't need the answer anymore.  But just in case someone else stumbles across this like I did...*

---

The forever process exits after it launches the actual `node app.js` process.

Since you do not specify a service `Type=`, then the default is "simple" (since you have `ExecStart=`), which expects the main process to continue running.  So when the main "forever" process drops, systemd thinks it has failed, since it's not aware that a child process has spawned.

Try adding `Type=forking` under `[Service]`.

As the [systemd.service documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Type=) states:

> If set to forking, it is expected that the process configured with ExecStart= will call fork() as part of its start-up. **The parent process is expected to exit** when start-up is complete and all communication channels are set up. **The child continues to run** as the main service process, and the service manager will consider the unit started when the parent process exits.